# How to use SUM inside COALESCE in JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq, mysql-5.6

Given below is a gist of the query, which I'm able to run successfully in `MySQL`

```
SELECT a.*, 
COALESCE(SUM(condition1 or condition2), 0) as countColumn
FROM table a 
-- left joins with multiple tables
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Now, I'm trying to use it with JOOQ.

```
ctx.select(a.asterisk(),                
            coalesce(sum("How to get this ?")).as("columnCount"))
            .from(a)
            .leftJoin(b).on(someCondition)
            .leftJoin(c).on(someCondition))
            .leftJoin(d).on(someCondition)
            .leftJoin(e).on(someCondition)
            .groupBy(a.ID);
```

I'm having a hard time preparing the `coalesce()` part, and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Hi @roshan, I am also facing the same issue. Could you please let me know how you used coalesce with sum in JOOQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ's API is more strict about the distinction between `Condition` and `Field<Boolean>`, which means you cannot simply treat booleans as numbers as you can in MySQL. It's usually not a bad idea to be explicit about data types to prevent edge cases, so this strictness isn't necessarly a bad thing.

So, you can transform your booleans to integers as follows:

```java
coalesce(
  sum(
    when(condition1.or(condition2), inline(1))
    .else_(inline(0))
  ), 
  inline(0)
)
```

But even better than that, why not use a [standard SQL `FILTER` clause](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/aggregate-filter/), which can be emulated in MySQL using a `COUNT(CASE ...)` aggregate function:

```java
count().filterWhere(condition1.or(condition2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Lukas, turns out `FILTER` was exactly what I was looking for.